# Minimal Bash-like line editing is suported; for the first word, TAB lists possible device or file completions; grub

Tags: linux, arch-linux, grub2, dual-boot, grub

Installed Arch Linux next to Windows. Did everything according to the instructions at https://pingvinus.ru/note/archlinux-install#partitioning-free. but after removing the bootable USB flash drive and rebooting it displays

> ```
> Minimal Bash-like line editing is supported
> ```

And hornbeam console on a black screen.

What's the matter?